# mod_rewrite to direct all images to domain specfic folder

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I would like to redirect all images that are loaded in my website to a domain specific folder. for example if I had a page on localhost with an `<img src="/media/images/123.jpg" />` tag (or even a background image)
I would like to store the image in "/domains/localhost/media/images/123.jpg".
I have the this rule so far but am missing something.

```
RewriteRule ^/media/images/(.*\.(jp?g|gif|bmp|png))$ /domains/%{REMOTE_HOST}/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Is this rule in `.htaccess` or in apache `.conf` file?

Comment: .htaccess  There is already a  RewriteRule . /index.php [L] moving all pages to a single page above it.

Comment: I think the second media/images is not needed but still no luck RewriteRule ^/media/images/(.*\.(jp?g|gif|bmp|png))$ /domains/%{REMOTE_HOST}/$1 [L]

Answer (score 0):

1) In per-directory context (`<Directory>` or `.htaccess`), RewriteRule pattern is matched against only a partial path, without the leading `/`.

2) If by "domain" you mean domain name which user entered in their browser address bar, you should use `%{HTTP_HOST}`, not `%{REMOTE_HOST}`

```
RewriteRule ^media/images/(.*\.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png))$ /domains/%{HTTP_HOST}/media/images/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/domains/.*/media/images/
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Comment: 'browser address bar' that is what I am worried about. I'm not too concerned with that address bar. I just hope this is not the only type of url that can be redirected. I need the embedded image urls in the html css and js to be redirected. I hope there is a way to do this.

Comment: With the above rules, it should be handled properly.